# highchart - add new data when submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to add more data after changing and submitting new value in the textbox.
if I change the data series to signal, it could load the chart with the data perfectly. but now I need it to be able to save the previous data and add the newly submitted data. how can I do that? what did I do wrong here?

here is my code

```js
$(function() {
  var valtemp1 = new Array(1024);

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    var val1, val2, options;

    val1 = parseFloat($("input[id=amplitudo]").val());
    val2 = parseFloat($("input[id=frequensi]").val());

    var osc = new Oscillator(DSP.Sine, val2, val1, 1024, 1024);
    osc.generate();
    var signal = osc.signal;

    for (var i = 0; i < signal.length; i++) {
      var w = signal[i] + valtemp1[i];
      valtemp1[i] = w;
    }

    options = {
      plotOptions: {
        spline: {
          lineWidth: 4,
          states: {
            hover: {
              lineWidth: 5
            }
          },
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          },
          pointInterval: 1,
          pointStart: 0
        }
      },

      series: [{
        type: "spline",
        name: "1",
        data: valtemp1
      }]
    };

    $("#wadah").highcharts(options);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="dsp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test1.js"></script>


<body>
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="card mb-3" style="height:500px">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form method="POST">
              <label for="test">amplitudo</label><br />
              <input type="textbox" id="amplitudo" value="" />
              <br />

              <label for="test2">Frequensi</label>
              <input type="textbox" id="frequensi" value="" />
              <br /><br />

              <input type="submit" value="hitung" id="btn" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9" style="height: 50px">
        <div id="wadah"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @nulla, You can use `addPoint` method to add new points. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/spn58gL3/

Comment: @ppotaczek i've tried that but when i submit it, the page got reloaded...
can you do an example where it got submitted with a form??

Comment: Yes, sure - please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zxbsuyk6/

Comment: @ppotaczek i dont think i know how to put it properly into my code.. im new to javascript, do you mind doing it with my code? and can you tell me where i do wrong? thanks for the help!!

Comment: Sure, but please reproduce that problem in jsfiddle.